# How do I prove that modular form of weight 0 has maximum value in its fundamental domain?

Tags: number-theory

How do I prove that the modular form of weight 0 for a group $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is constant in its fundamental domain?

I was trying to express f in terms of the Fourier series since it's periodic but I am uncertain how to show the convergence of fourier series in the complex space. Is there any better way to see it? Could anyone suggest any direction or provide tips?

Comment: The usual way to prove there are no non-constant modular forms of weight 0 for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (and that 0 is the only odd or negative weight form, etc.) is to use the [valence formula](https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/seminars/ws0607/modular-forms/valence_formula_and_the_space_of_modular_forms.pdf), but I am not sure about a direct proof.

Comment: Valence formula makes sense! but I want to use maximum modulus principle, and in order to use it I have to know it has a maximum in fundamental domain